# Threejs 360 stereoscopic video

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality

When I look at this demo from three js in my mobile device I get duplicate screen:

[image]

https://threejs.org/examples/#webxr_vr_video

When I look at some youtube 360 stereoscopic video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR5LEg1rpUo&ab_channel=BLUERAVENstudios I get normal behavior.

Is this the correct behavior for three js demo ? What is picture divided in 2 parts? Can this three js demo behave the same as youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct behavior for that Three.js demo. [See here for WebXR description on each device](https://immersiveweb.dev/). Specifically, you're interested in the part that reads:

> Enable VR by providing pose information and allowing the WebGL scene to be rendered side by side to be placed in a headset like the Cardboard

So the reason you're seeing it side-by-side is because you need a [Google Cardboard](https://arvr.google.com/cardboard/) to get the VR experience.

Comment: Does this mean video is different (video on three demo and youtube example I posted) or it just means the code is different.  If I were to use youtube video in three demo, result would be the same, splitted view?

Comment: The video file is the same for left and right channels. It’s a single .mp4 that gets rendered twice. If you use the YouTube video, the result would still be split into two.

Comment: so this is like monoscopic vs stereoscopic video?